# Strange Javascript issue when using placeholders html5

Tags: jquery, html, placeholder

Im using placeholders.js but I'm getting the following error in console...

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Placeholders.init({
                    live: true,
                    hideOnFocus: false,
                    className: "yourClass",
                    textColor: "#999"
                    })')
complete (main.js, line 416)
j (modernizr.js, line 4)
(anonymous function) (modernizr.js, line 4)
h (modernizr.js, line 4)
onload (modernizr.js, line 4)
```

Here is my code around these lines can anyone see whats wrong with this i have been trying all sorts for hours now and i just can't fathom it out.

```
if (!Modernizr.placeholder) {
Placeholders.init({
live: true,
hideOnFocus: false,
className: "yourClass",
textColor: "#999"
});    
}
```

Comment: This might be too simple a question, but have you edited "yourClass" to reference the actual class attribute of the input on which you added a placeholder element?

Comment: yes I've tried that, i hoped it was that simple too but sadly not :( thanks for replying though.

Comment: You are loading the placeholder polyfill before that script block (either as a script tag, or with `Modernizr.load`)?

Answer (score 7):

Were you trying to use the Brushed web page template found [here](http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/brushed-template/)? I had the same issue trying to use that template, as it contains the exact same code you posted.

To resolve my issue, I went to [Placeholders' Github page](http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/) to check out the interface. There, I found that there is no init() function defined in the Placeholders.js file, and under the Setup section it says:

> Placeholders.js is incredibly easy to use. Just download the script, include it at the bottom of any web page and let it do the rest. It's just one extra line in your markup.

So, don't worry about calling the init() function. All you have to do is include the Placeholders.js file, nothing else. With that, my error disappeared! I know this is a late response, but I hope it helps someone.